# How does an interface communicate - Need a detailed answer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I have a fragment class:

```
public class UploadFragmentOne extends Fragment {}
```

I have subclassed:

```
 public interface Communicator {
        void communicate(int position);
    }
```

In the onCreateView:

```
 ((Communicator) getActivity()).communicate(1);
```

The hosting activity signature:

```
public class DetailsPager extends FragmentActivity implements UploadFragmentOne.Communicator {}
```

Member function in the above activity:

```
 public void communicate(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(DetailsPager.this, "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This works like a charm, but I dont understand HOW? Sorry this might be too dumb, but I want to know how the control flows in this?

Comment: `can you tell what exactly you are not getting`?

Comment: `((Communicator) getActivity()).communicate(1);`  when I could have done it simply like `(MyActivity)activity.some_method().`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944539/abstract-class-real-time-example) once.-
Now come to your query

```
(MyActivity)activity.some_method()
```

Now suppose you are going to attach the same fragment for another activity say `MainActivity` then you need to do like -

```
(MainActivity)activity.some_method()
```

Now suppose some other activity are implementing the same fragment then each time you need to use the `instanceOf` check and then call the method and also add it.

Again suppose a trivial case when you are going the create a library and you are going to offer some result delivery for the particular event then?
How will you get the instance type ?

interface as the name suggests offer a way to be communicated without the actual class instance. They only need to be implemented. You can have a look on the `OnClickListener` in the `View` class of android API sources.