# Interface in java

Tags: interface

```
interface A {
    public void eg1();
}

interface B {
    public void eg1();
}

public class SomeOtherClassName implements A, B {
    @Override
    public void eg1() {
        System.out.println("test.eg1()");
    }

}
```

What is the output and what occurs if method is overriden  in interface?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all it's of no use to implement both class A and B as both
  of them has same method signature i.e both has same method name and
  return type.
- Secondly you'll need a main method to run the program.
- Also in interface you can only declare the methods, the implementation
  has to be done in the class which implements it.

  ```
   interface A {
      public void eg1();
  }

  interface B {
      public void eg1();
  }

  public class Test implements A{
      @Override
      public void eg1() {
          System.out.println("test.eg1()");
      }
      public static void main (String args[]) {
          A a = new test();
          a.eg1();
      }
  }
  ```

**Output** : test.eg1()

Comment: refer this for further understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944539/abstract-class-real-time-example